# Getting "Connection refused" when running nodetool on Cassandra cluster on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cassandra, ubuntu-18.04

I just did the setup of a cassandra cluster.
I have changed the `seed`, `listen_adress` and `broadcast_adress` in the `cassandra.yalm` file. But when I run the command

```
$ nodetool flush system
```

Cmd retrun this error,

```
nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException:
'Connection refused (Connection refused)'.
```

in the file etc/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh I made the modification JVM_OPTS as on the screenshot

[image]

I use aws at the beginning I was on a t2.micro server. But I switched to a t2.large as recommended in many articles.

Finally, my ports are open as shown in this screenshot and I'm use ubuntu.

[image]

Comment: Where are you running nodetool from? A shell inside one of the instances or from your local machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, remote JMX connections to Cassandra nodes are disabled. If you're running `nodetool` commands on the EC2 instance itself, it isn't necessary to modify the JVM options `cassandra-env.sh`.

In fact, we discourage allowing remote JMX connections for security reasons. Only allow remote access if you're an expert and know what you're doing. Cheers!

Comment: yes but even if the cassandra-env.sh file is not modified i still get the error so how to do?

Comment: Have you confirmed that Cassandra is running? Check the logs for clues. Cheers!